# C++ runtime Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a C++ application that runs well on a few machines. But I found more than one PCs that the application fails on them with the error:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

What's interesting is that in one computer it partly works and partly not. A few days ago it failed with the error and now it works.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: this behavior is because of undefined behavior )

Comment: You could try debugging the application, if you have no debugger on that machine try using logging to find the location of the error.

Comment: I think there's a good chance you got compile warnings. If not, turn up the warning level. And pay attention to the warnings!

Comment: This message means your application threw an exception which wasn't caught.  Add a catch block at the top level which will actually display the information in the exception, so that when this happens you'll know more than "FAIL".

Answer (score 1):

The correct attitude isn't that it fails on some machines - it is that "my program is wrong **everywhere** - it just coincidently happens to work on certain machines"

The most likely is an uninitialized variable which happens to point to empty and zero-ed memory on the *working* machine but points at junk on the others, or you aren't checking if some allocation fails and the working machine has lots of memeory . Another common problem is a different version of some runtime library.

Suggestions:
Turn up the warning level on the compiler
Try a debug build - these generally set all variables to zero
This is a great opportunity to learn about stack dumps and remote debugging

Comment: It might also be useful to generate core dumps to analyze the state when the program crashes (if the problem isn't evident in debug), also having a symbols database (PDB?) can't hurt for the release configuration.